# Is there any open-source project like wix gui editor and it can build static files?

Tags: windows, open-source, html, editor

Wix gui editor is awesome (I paid for it for five website) but it can't download static html5 file and using on other site project legally. so now I'm using `RocketCake` and `VScode + chrome dev tool` , they're good tools but not update gui dev tool `for long time`.

Is there any open-source project like wix gui editor and it can build static files?

Wix :

[image: image-20200727170603717]

RocketCake

[image: image-20200727165210332]

Comment: Welcome Wei!  When you say "open project", do you mean an open-source project?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasketR yes,open-source project,thanks i edited it!

Comment: Thanks Wei! I added the open-source tag for you as well.